# C# Regex Substituons

Tags: regex

Could you help me?
I'm begning in Regular Expression, and I need to create about 50 pattern of Regular expression substituion.

One of these pattern samples is 000100954-1/001 need to be 100954-1. But I have no idea how to implement this.

I would like just a example, and some articles reference that will give me more knowledge about this.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: learn and test your regex here http://regexr.com/    I would also suggest looking for "trim leading zeros" regex

Comment: please provide a more detailed description of your requirements, together with an example of input data and the result that you are trying to get

Comment: what is your rules to convert `000100954-1/001 to be 100951-1` ?

Comment: sorry. I mean   input 000100954-1/001, output 100954-1.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C# .net 4.6

Comment: @TiagoGomes ok. I am not sure if I the solution that is written in JavaScript helps. It is about how to use replace(). Let me know if you want to see the solution that is in JS

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rules based on your single sample,

```
var ans = Regex.Replace("000100954-1/001", @"[^0]+-[0-9]+");
```

Should work.